# Construction of a triangle, given: side, sum of the other sides and angle between known side and one unknown side.

Tags: trigonometry

You know the length of one side, A. The sum of the other two sides is K=B+C. You know the angle between A and B. Is this solvable? [image]

Comment: yep, i did that few years ago

Comment: Just some intuition to make sure that $B$ and $C$ are fixed by $K$: By looking at the picture we see that $K$ is a continuous and strictly increasing function of $B$, and by letting $B \to 0$ we can find a solution for any $K > A$. This isn't rigorous of course, but indicates that it makes sense to hunt for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

- Draw side BC(known).
- Draw angle $\theta$, say $\angle$ XBC.
- Cut a line segment $BD=K$ (that is equal to AB+AC) from the ray BX.
- Join DC and make an angle DCY equal to $\angle$BDC.
- Let CY intersect BX at A. $\triangle$ABC is the required triangle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By the [cosine theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) you can solve this. Substitute $B = K-C$ into the formula
$A^2+B^2-2AB\cos \Theta = C^2$.

You will arive to a quadratic equation that you can solve by $C$.